# Implementing jquery step by step from onto HTML page

Tags: jquery

I've tried to implement the following jquery example: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/5/

onto an HTML page: http://licf.ronaldboadi.com/test.html

but the results differ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you compared the code from each example to see how they're different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firebug console shows the following error:

```
illegal character

});​
```

line 48, column 11

Get rid of the very last semicolon

```
  $(function(){
    // Code
  }) // No semicolon
```